# What to do with tide related tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed [tidal.force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tidal.force) today.

Now clearly, that have a `.` where we expect a `-`, so it needs to be fixed, but what *should* the tag be.

The other existing tide related tag is [tidal-effect](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tidal-effect) which has the right form.

Do we like

- [tide](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tide)
- [tidal-force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tidal-force)
- [tidal-effect](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tidal-effect)
- others??

more than one? If more than one what are the distinctions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Physically, it seems like these are all referring to the same thing, so personally I'd be inclined to just merge them all into [tidal-effect](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tidal-effect). At least, I definitely wouldn't use [tide](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tide) because that suggests ocean tides on the Earth, which is only one example of the tidal effect.

Comment: This was the way I was leaning as well.